# Clarification on the usage of Semaphores vs task notifcations vs queues

Tags: microcontroller, embedded, freertos

I'm trying to understand the basic concepts of FreeRTOS.

- When do you use queues vs task notifications? I see queues are used for task-task, task-interrupt synchronization i.e one task waiting on a queue via `xQueueReceive()` while the ISR is populating the queue. So in an ISR, you'd call `xQueueSendToBackFromISR()`.
  You could get around the same behaviour via task notifications by using `ulTaskNotifyTake()` in the blocked task and `xTaskNotifyFromISR()` in the task that's supposed to unblock the other task, except you aren't writing/reading from a queue. Or is it that when you want to send data or something to a task, queues should be used and otherwise notifications?
- When do you use task notifications vs semaphore? I see task notifications can act as a semaphore...

Answer (score 3):

A Task Notification is specific to a task. Each task has one, and any other task (or interrupt handler) can 'post' to it to notify that task that some event has occurred.
You don't need to configure a Task Notification - every task has one as soon as it starts up.

A Semaphore is created independently of any one particular task - it doesn't 'belong' to the task which created it. Any task can wait on any semaphore, and any task (or interrupt handler) can give to any semaphore. Multiple tasks can all wait on the same semaphore.

A Queue is sort-of like a pipe. Tasks or interrupt handlers can push things in one end and other tasks or interrupt handlers (or even the same task) can pull these things out the other end. Depending on how the queue is configured, it can often hold many things inside it at once (unlike a Task Notification which can only hold a single 32-bit value).
Many tasks can push into the same queue, and many tasks can also pull from it, but once an item gets pulled from the queue it's gone and other tasks can't get it (although FreeRTOS does offer a function to 'peek' into the queue without pulling stuff out).
Some OSes (FreeRTOS being one of them) allow you to 'jump the queue' by pushing things straight to the front of the queue (instead of to the back where they would normally go).

Comment: mind elaborating on posting to a task? How I imagined task notifications is merely a a way of signalling another task/interrupt by removing/adding to the ready list. What I see in `xTaskNotifyFromISR()` is it adds the task to a ready list while `ulTaskNotifyTake()` adds the task to a delayed list in the first part of the critical section. Also I see the second part of the critical section runs only after `xTaskNotifyFromISR()` is called. Not exactly sure why.

Comment: A task doesn't have to be blocked or on FreeRTOS's delayed list to receive a notification. A currently running task could receive a notification from an ISR for example. Similarly, if a task is blocked waiting for some other reason (for example a mutex), then sending it a notification won't wake it up.

Comment: Calling 'ulTaskNotifyTake' will not necessarily block the task either. If the 'xTicksToWait' parameter is 0 or the task's notification value is already non-0 then the call will return immediately and the task will not be blocked.

Comment: yeah, the task remains blocked till `xTicksToWait` times out. I was using max delay time which would keep the task blocked till it gets notified but my main concern was how does the second part of the critical section get executed after either the timeout or when `xTaskNotifyFromISR()` is invoked...